# How to separate date input bootstrap Date Range Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have form that use `daterangepicker`

url : https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker

I was able to attach `daterangepicker` into my form with this simple script.

```
script 

//Date range picker
$('.daterp').daterangepicker();

/script
```

and just add class to my form.

```
class="form-control daterp"
```

so it will be

```
<input type="text" name="start_date" style="width: 100%;" required="" class="form-control daterp" id="id_start_date">
```

when I click submit its give me like `07/29/2018 - 07/29/2018` submitted to my database.

that not what I need.

imagine my database table like this

```
#table shift
+---------------+---------------+
| start         | end           |
+---------------+---------------+
| 2018-01-01    | 2018-01-05    | 
| 2018-01-08    | 2018-01-14    |
| ....          | ....          |
+---------------+---------------+
```

What I need when I click submit on my `form field` with value `07/29/2018 - 07/29/2018`

`07/29/2018` is going to `start`

and

`07/29/2018` is going to `end`

but with only single `form field`

how to do that?...

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can check out this [link](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/issues/222)

```
$('#someinput').daterangepicker(options, callback);
//parse the start date & end date
startDate = $('#someinput').data('daterangepicker').startDate;
endDate = $('#someinput').data('daterangepicker').endDate;

//format it 
Start = start_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
End = end_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be sent to the form in a single field, then it seems to be that you're going to need to parse that single field out on the back end using whatever code your back end is running.

But it sounds to me like what you really want is to separate the dates into two separate fields.  So change the name of the main field to "date_range" and add two hidden fields called "start_date" and "end_date", then either on form submit or on an event tied to the date range picker, split the values like so:

```
$('#start_date').val( $('#date_range').text().split(' - ')[0]);
$('#end_date').val( $('#date_range').text().split(' - ')[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the date range string by `' - '` delimiter on your back-end. If you use node.js you could try to do

```
[startDate, endDate] = '07/12/2018 - 07/28/2018'.split(' - ');
```

Or if you use PHP

```
list($startDate, $endDate) = explode(' - ', $_POST['start_date']);
```

The other solution is to use set the values before form submission
For example,
In HTML:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="date_range">
    <input type="hidden" name="start_date">
    <input type="hidden" name="end_date">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In JS:

```
$('input.date_range').daterangepicker();
$('form').submit(function (ev, picker) {
    [startDate, endDate] = $('.date_range').val().split(' - ');
    $(this).find('input[name="start_date"]').val(startDate);
    $(this).find('input[name="end_date"]').val(endDate);
});
```

Comment: No need to do string parsing since separate dates can be accessed directly as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61506543/707926